# Can a print server serve multiple printers?

Tags: networking, printing, print-server

Let's say a corporation doesn't want to take up IP address space with a bunch of network printers. Let's say the company decides to dedicate one room on each floor to all the printers for that floor, and to have one print server (probably a Linux machine rather than an off-the shelf box) serve them all. This allows one IP address to serve, say, five printers, and the server handles which print jobs go to which printers, allowing multiple simultaneous print jobs.

Is such a situation possible, or can a print server only handle one printer?

Comment: Yes.  Even 20 year old HP JetDirect boxes (with both ethernet *and* BNC connectors) could be had with multiple parallel ports on them.  Or look at CUPS on a Mac or Linux system wtih a physical printer - there will often be a PDF printer, etc. as well.

Comment: Are you truly limited to one IP address for the entire setup? If so, all of the printers would have to be directly connected to the print server (not over the network which would require IP addresses for each). But having all printers in a single location seems like an artificial constraint.

Comment: I said one room on each floor, where all the printers are. All of this is theoretical anyway. Each floor would have a different print server with its own IP address in the printer room on that floor, and all the printers for that floor would be in that room with a USB connection to the server.